# which are the rewritten candidates for != operator

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

The relevant rule in the standars says:
[over.match.oper#3.4.3](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3.4.3)

> The rewritten candidate set is determined as follows:
>
> > 1. For the relational ([expr.rel]) operators, the rewritten candidates include all non-rewritten candidates for the expression x <=> y.
> > 2. For the relational ([expr.rel]) and three-way comparison ([expr.spaceship]) operators, the rewritten candidates also include a synthesized candidate, with the order of the two parameters reversed, for each non-rewritten candidate for the expression y <=> x.
> > 3. For the != operator ([expr.eq]), the rewritten candidates include **all non-rewritten candidates** for the expression x == y.
> > 4. For the equality operators, the rewritten candidates also include a synthesized candidate, with the order of the two parameters reversed, for each non-rewritten candidate for the expression y == x.
> > 5. For all other operators, the rewritten candidate set is empty.

Consider the following [code](https://godbolt.org/z/51E8he):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct Data{
    bool operator ==(int c){
      return true;
    }
};
int main(){
   Data d;
   bool r = 0 != d;  // should be ill-formed
}
```

I don't know why the code can be compiled by the compiler. IMO,  the rewritten candidates for expression `0!=d` should include **all non-rewritten candidates** for the expression x == y. My understanding of the wording **non-rewritten candidates** is, consider any candidates other than the rewritten candidates for the expression x==y for operation x != y. After all, bullet 4 is used to form a rewritten candidate set. So, the fourth bullet should not continue to apply to the `x==y` that has been rewritten for the original expression `x!=y`. In my example, the rewritten candidate set for `0!=d` contains only that for `0==d`, which should not consider any rewritten candidate for `d==0`;

The relevant rule in this [page](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1630r1.html#wording) for wording **non-rewritten** has a similar interpretation with mine. (exclude rewritten candidate)

> For the != operator ([expr.eq]), the rewritten candidates include all **member, non-member, and built-in candidates** for the expression x == y.

However, continue to look at the next paragraph, that is:

> If a rewritten operator== candidate is selected by overload resolution for an operator @, its return type shall be cv bool, and x @ y is interpreted as:
>
> > - if @ is != and **the selected candidate is a synthesized candidate with reversed order of parameters**, !(y == x),

Since the rewritten candidate for `!=` cannot be continued to rewrite, how could it have a synthesized candidate with reversed order of parameters? I don't know why. How to interpret the rule of the rewritten candidates for `!=`, particularly the wording **non-rewritten candidate** and the last rule?

Comment: Given rule 3 and 4 and a bit of common sense, one can easily figure out that both rules can be applied. Thus **non rewritten** essentially apply to user code.

Comment: @cigien I forgot to add  `c++`.

Comment: @Phil1970 I don't understand your meaning. IMO, **include all non-rewritten candidates** means consider any candidates other than the rewritten candidates for the expression  `x==y` for operation `x != y`.  After all, bullet 4 is used to form a **rewritten candidate set**

Comment: @Phil1970 Take a look at this [page](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1630r1.html#wording), the interpretation of **non-rewritten** wording is similar to mine. However, it still cannot interpret `if @ is != and the selected candidate is a synthesized candidate with reversed order of parameters, !(y == x),`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that this is granted by [[over.match.oper]/3.4.4](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3.4.4):

> For the **equality operators**, the rewritten candidates also include a **synthesized** candidate, with the order of the two parameters reversed, for each non-rewritten candidate for the expression y == x.

Equality operators are *both* `operator==` and `operator!=`. Also note "synthesized" is not synonymous with "rewritten": the four sets of candidates are *member candidates*, *non-member candidates*, *built-in candidates*, and *rewritten candidates*. A synthesized candidate merely belongs to one of these sets (in this case the set of rewritten candidates).

As such, my understanding is the rewritten candidates for `x != y` include both

- all non-rewritten candidates for `x == y`, and also
- synthesized candidates for non-rewritten candidates for `y == x`.

So the synthesized candidate for `y == x` is also rewritten candidate. Then [[over.match.oper]/9.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#9.1) kicks in:

> if `@` is `!=` and the selected candidate is a synthesized candidate with reversed order of parameters, `!(y == x)`

That is, if the rewritten candidate selected is the above synthesized candidate of `y == x`, then the result will be `!(y == x)`.

Comment: Thanks. Consider the bullet 4, Does it mean the candidates include both "each non-rewritten candidate for the expression y == x" and the synthesized candidate for each former, or just include the synthesized candidate for each former?

Comment: @jack X Algorithmically, I believe it's more like: "Consider the expression `y == x`. Collect all candidates `C` for that expression, excluding the set of rewritten candidates. For each candidate `c` in `C`, synthesize a new candidate `f` with the parameters reversed. Each candidate `f` is then added to the set of rewritten candidates for `x @ y`."

Comment: I see a wonderful interpretation. Then the argument-list that used to determine which is best is (x, y) rather than (y, x), Right?

Comment: @jackX yup, exactly. (And the argument list `x, y` is used to select from _all_ candidates remember, not just the rewritten ones – /9 is just used when the selected candidate happens to be in the set of rewritten candidates.)

Comment: do you know what's the paper name that introduced "rewritten candidates"? was this just part of spaceship paper somehow?